# Combine multiple debounce promises in JS

Tags: javascript, npm, es6-promise

I would like to optimize multiple expensive server calls by repeatedly calling a function that takes a key, and returns a promise of an object. When resolved, the object is guaranteed to contain the needed key + some value, and it could contain other unrelated keys. The function would:

- on first call, create a promise
- on each call, accumulate keys to be sent to the server
- all calls return the same promise until 100ms of quiet time
- when no calls are made for 100 ms, call the server to process all the keys accumulated so far
- if a new call is made, even if the server hasn't responded yet, treat it as the "first call" by starting a new promise with its own set of pending keys
- when server call returns, resolve the pending promise

Are there any NPM libs that would help with this, or should I write it from scratch?

Comment: Regarding the "guarantee" part - if the consolidated promise rejects because of a communication failure, all recipients of the promise can catch the rejection. But if a particular key is unknown, recipients of valid keys should continue. So my suggestion would be to return an invalid value from the server for individual invalid keys. Otherwise the algorithm looks fine (28 lines of code to mock up ;-) )

Answer (score 1):

Searching for "NPM consolidate server requests using a single promise" or "... accumulate server requests... " didn't turn up anything obvious. I'll share the mockup code using ES6 promises mentioned in comment to perhaps form the basis of a solution in the absence of other suggestions. As is, not guaranteed etc...

```
/*******  application code  ********/

function requestKeys( keyArray) {
    // promise an oject for values of keys in keyArray:
    // use asynchronous code to get values for keys in keyArray,
    // return a promise for the parsed result object.
    // ...
}

const latency = 100; // maximum latency between getting a key and making a request

/********  generic code *********/

var getKey = (( requestKeys, latency) => {
    // return a function to return a promise of a key value object
    var promise = null;
    var resolve = null;
    var reject = null;
    var pendingKeys = null;

    var defer = () => {
        promise = new Promise( (r,j) => {resolve = r; reject = j});
        pendingKeys = [];
    };

    var running = false;
    var timesUp = () => {
        resolve( requestKeys( pendingKeys));
        running = false;
    }
    var addKey = ( key) => {
        if(! running) {
            defer();
            setTimeout( timesUp, latency);
            running = true;
        }
        pendingKeys.push( key);
        return promise;
    }
    return addKey;
})( requestKeys, latency);


/*******   test code   *******/

// redefine requestKeys to promise an object with key strings as key values,
// resolve the return promise synchronously for testing:

function requestKeys( keyArray) {
    var keyObj = keyArray.reduce( ((obj, v) => ((obj[v] = v), obj) ), {} );
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => resolve(keyObj) );
}

var log = obj => console.log( JSON.stringify(obj));

// get two keys quickly
getKey("holas").then( log);
getKey("buono").then( log);

// wait and get another
setTimeout( function(){getKey('later').then( log)}, 500);
```